# WTForms how to replace {{}} inside {{}}

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I m pretty sure by title, this is unclear to you.
Here is my code

```
{{wtf.quick_form(form, action='/edit?id={{id}}', method='POST')}}
```

Now I want to replace {{id}} with id that'll be passed to html page by flask but now, it is not replace {{id}} with the actual id(1)
So how can I fix this?
I use WtForms, python, Flask, Flaskform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the static part with the dynamic part.

Use

```
{{wtf.quick_form(form, action='/edit?id=' ~ id, method='POST')}}
```

or

```
{{wtf.quick_form(form, action='/edit?id=%s' % id, method='POST')}}
```